# how to get order of input related to points in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

want to get 3 Point3D from the user and also he/she can determine how these points are

conneced.

I want to use this in  `MeshGeometry3D` and `mesh.Positions.Add` and `mesh.TriangleIndices.Add`

in XAML :

```
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"    Width="Auto"   Text="Point 1" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
     <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"    Text="0,0,0"   Width="50" Margin="2"  Name="textbox1"></TextBox>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"      Text="Point 2" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
       <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   Text="0,0,0"   Width="50" Margin="2"   Name="textbox2"></TextBox>
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Width="Auto"  Text="Point 3" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
       <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"    Text="0,0,0"   Width="50" Margin="2"  Name="textbox3"></TextBox>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Width="Auto"   Text="Path" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"    Text="1,3,2" Width="50" Margin="2"   Name="pathtxt"></TextBox>
```

in code behind :

```
        Point3D p1 = Point3D.Parse(textbox1.Text);
        Point3D p2 = Point3D.Parse(textbox2.Text);
        Point3D p3 = Point3D.Parse(textbox3.Text);

        string[] path = pathtxt.Text.Split(',');

       MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

       //mesh.Positions.Add(????);  ???
```

it is simple to determine path  by myself for example :

```
        mesh.Positions.Add(p1);
        mesh.Positions.Add(p2);
        mesh.Positions.Add(p3);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
```

but how can i make it from user path ?

how to convert 1,3,2 to p1,p3,p2 ?

any idea ?

thanks for any help.

more explain :

the user input for point 1 is : 2,3,4 (for example) as the x,y,z of point1 and  Point3D p1 = Point3D.Parse(textbox1.Text) is correct parsing to point3d. so next step is important. the user input for path is : 1,2,3 (for example) => it means that : first connect point 1 to point2 and then connect point 2 to point 3.

Comment: Is that not parsing correctly? Your variables are holding the values the user typed into the textbox.

Comment: @ DonA : ok , so what is your idea to parsing correctly ?

Comment: @DonA : i want the user determine how the points are connected

Comment: That was a question - are they parsing the textbox input correctly. I don't understand - `how to convert 1,3,2 to p1,p3,p2 ?` What does the user input look like? Does it then need another modification?

Comment: @DonA : Hi , ok , the user input for point 1 is : 2,3,4 (for example) as the x,y,z of point1 and  Point3D p1 = Point3D.Parse(textbox1.Text) is correct parsing to point3d. so next step is important. the user input for path is : 1,2,3 (for example) => it means that : first connect point 1 to point2 and then connect point 2 to point 3. if you need more explain , let me know.

Comment: @DonA : any idea ? do you need more explain ?

Comment: Your triangles must match with the points given. Check out this [Cube](http://stuff.seans.com/2008/08/13/drawing-a-cube-in-wpf/) example.

Comment: @DonA : thanks i know , i have created box successfully. but the different is that the user determine the TriangleIndices. the problem is that i do not know how to convert  predefined TriangleIndices to  userdefined TriangleIndices from path input? thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the user the ability to create 8 `Point3D`s then you will need 8 text boxes obviously.

This means you will have to do 8 `mesh.Position.Add(..)`s.

Now you have to define your `TriangleIndices`; or in other words, ask the user to define the path.  So do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"    Width="Auto"   Text="Enter the path of your polygon keeping in mind the order you added your points" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"    Width="Auto"   Name="indices" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
```

Have the user enter something like this `"0,2,1,3,5,8,6,7,4"` in the `indices` textbox.

Do:

```
string[] idx = indicies.Text.Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i < idx.Length; i++)
{
    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(mesh.Positions[idx[i]]);
}
```

In this case, it would connect:

- `p1` with `p3`
- `p3` to `p2`
- `p2` to `p4`
- `//Assuming you had more points`
- `p4` to `p6`
- `p6` to `p8`

etc...

This can definitely be improved and should only be used to get an understanding.